# require_once can't find file on webserver but works on localhost

Tags: php

All,
I have the following files:

builder.php
Oauth.php
twitteroauth.php

Within my builder.php page I have the following code:

```
require_once('twitteroauth.php');
```

Then in my twitteroauth.php page I have the following code:

```
require_once('OAuth.php');
```

All of these files are in the following path: wp-content/themes/alyeska/framework/frontend/functions

I'm testing this on my localhost and it works fine. However, when I upload all of these files to my webserver I get the following error message:

Warning: require_once(OAuth.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/arokyne/website.com/wp-content/themes/alyeska/framework/frontend/functions/twitteroauth.php on line 10

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'OAuth.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php5/lib/pear') in /home/arokyne/website.com/wp-content/themes/alyeska/framework/frontend/functions/twitteroauth.php on line 10

I'm not sure why I'm getting these errors since it works on my localhost. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Windows vs Linux a.k.a case sensitiveness?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things jump to mind- make certain your path is correct, including the case sensitivity; also, make certain that the permissions on the file allow for the php server to read the file.  A 644 mode should be sufficient, I believe; but, worst case, a 755 would definitely work.

And finally you may want to check whether your include path is correct.

Comment: It was an issue with the case sensitivity. Thanks

Comment: I just spend 2 hours on this exact issue @user1048676 had. I didn't believe it was case sensitivity issue at all but when I looked again it was. Localhost didn't care which was why it worked but not on the other server. Thank you very much.